# Unknown chromium error: -6 on Android but not iOS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I tried to test it in real device and simulator, in iOS it works well, but not on Android (so far have tested it on Android 2.2 emulator and Android 4.0.4 device), it gives this error:

```
Unknown chromium error: -6
```

This error occurs when I tried to navigate to other page:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" class="fullWidth" data-ajax="false" rel="extrenal">Login</a>
```

Js:

```
$('#login').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    jq.mobile.changePage("pendingChecklist.html", { transition: animation, changeHash: true });
});
```

As far as I can gather information out there, the error is caused by ICS browser bugs but unfortunately this also happens on Android 2.2 emulator. I also have tried solutions out there but no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I too get it in my PhoneGap application. But this error doesn't cause the app to halt or crash in my experience.

Please check the DDMS for any other blocking issue in the log if your application is crashing. Errors are usually logged in Red color.

You can ignore it and move on. Can you also provide with the logcat so we can see whether something went wrong somewhere.

### Update

instead of below line

```
jq.mobile.changePage("pendingChecklist.html", { transition: animation, changeHash: true })
```

can you plece this line and check

```
window.location.href="pendingChecklist.html";
```

It may be a issue with `changePage` method.

Comment: It only prints that error. But the bad thing is the screen isn't navigated to next screen. That's why I'm asking here :) I will provide the logcat soon

Comment: @Rendy yeah please place that here :) also check the updated answer.

Comment: This is very strange. Now the app suddenly works as it's intended -_-

Comment: @MayuMayooresan I apologize to troublesome you and spam stackoverflow lol

Comment: @Rendy ha ha no worries. Chromium error won't stop your app. If app doesn't work probably its an issue with your code. does it works when you use `location.href` or just started to work as expected??

Comment: Mayu Mayooresan: it just works as expected using my code.. Not sure why lol..
Aaron Springer: yes I also believe it's the cause but actually it works on iOS but not on Android previously.